# IO tasks easily starve eachother on 3Ware 9650SE

Tags: linux, io, 3ware

I have a server (Debian 6 LTS) with a 3Ware 9650 SE RAID controller. There are two arrays, one RAID1, one RAID6. It runs Xen 4.0, with about 18 DomUs. The problem is that I experience that IO tasks very easily starve each other. It happens when one DomU generates a lot of IO, blocking the others for minutes at a time, but it also just happened while `dd`'ing.

To move a DomU off a busy RAID array, I used dd. While doing that, not only did my Nagios report other VMs to be unresponsive, I got this notice on the Dom0:

```
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]  INFO: task kdmflush:1683 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]  "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]  kdmflush      D 0000000000000002     0  1683      2 0x00000000
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   ffff88001fd37810 0000000000000246 ffff88001f742a00 ffff8800126c4680
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   ffff88000217e400 00000000aae72d72 000000000000f9e0 ffff88000e65bfd8
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   00000000000157c0 00000000000157c0 ffff880002291530 ffff880002291828
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]  Call Trace:
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   [<ffffffff8106ce4e>] ? timekeeping_get_ns+0xe/0x2e
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   [<ffffffff8130deb2>] ? io_schedule+0x73/0xb7
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   [<ffffffffa0175bd6>] ? dm_wait_for_completion+0xf5/0x12a [dm_mod]
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   [<ffffffff8104b52e>] ? default_wake_function+0x0/0x9
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   [<ffffffffa01768c3>] ? dm_flush+0x1b/0x59 [dm_mod]
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   [<ffffffffa01769b9>] ? dm_wq_work+0xb8/0x167 [dm_mod]
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   [<ffffffff81062cfb>] ? worker_thread+0x188/0x21d
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   [<ffffffffa0176901>] ? dm_wq_work+0x0/0x167 [dm_mod]
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   [<ffffffff81066336>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x2e
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   [<ffffffff81062b73>] ? worker_thread+0x0/0x21d
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   [<ffffffff81066069>] ? kthread+0x79/0x81
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   [<ffffffff81012baa>] ? child_rip+0xa/0x20
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   [<ffffffff81011d61>] ? int_ret_from_sys_call+0x7/0x1b
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   [<ffffffff8101251d>] ? retint_restore_args+0x5/0x6
[2015-01-14 00:38:07]   [<ffffffff81012ba0>] ? child_rip+0x0/0x20
```

I tried both deadline and cfq schedulers. With the CFQ, it doesn't make a DomU more responsive if I set the `blkback` backend processes to realtime IO priority.

I gave the Dom0 a sched-cred of 10000, since it needs a higher weight to serve all the IO of the DomU's (and in my case doesn't do much else). But whatever I set that to, it should not influence the `dd` command and the `kdmflush` it blocked, since that is all Dom0.

This is the `tw_cli` output (just had a broken disk, hence the initializing. It's unrelated, because the problem has existed for a long time):

```
Unit  UnitType  Status         %RCmpl  %V/I/M  Stripe  Size(GB)  Cache  AVrfy
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
u0    RAID-6    INITIALIZING   -       89%(A)  256K    5587.9    RiW    ON     
u2    RAID-1    OK             -       -       -       1862.63   RiW    ON     

VPort Status         Unit Size      Type  Phy Encl-Slot    Model
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
p1    OK             u0   1.82 TB   SATA  1   -            WDC WD2000FYYZ-01UL 
p2    OK             u0   1.82 TB   SATA  2   -            ST32000542AS        
p3    OK             u0   1.82 TB   SATA  3   -            WDC WD2002FYPS-02W3 
p4    OK             u0   1.82 TB   SATA  4   -            ST32000542AS        
p5    OK             u0   1.82 TB   SATA  5   -            WDC WD2003FYYS-02W0 
p6    OK             u2   1.82 TB   SATA  6   -            WDC WD2002FYPS-02W3 
p7    OK             u2   1.82 TB   SATA  7   -            WDC WD2002FYPS-02W3 

Name  OnlineState  BBUReady  Status    Volt     Temp     Hours  LastCapTest
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bbu   On           Yes       OK        OK       OK       0      xx-xxx-xxxx
```

I really find this bizar and annoying. I have a feeling this is a quirk of the RAID controller. Other machines with software RAID perform much better.

I hope anyone can enlighten me.

Comment: RAID6 is very slow (RAID10 is faster then RAID5/6 & is generally best for VMs, databases and other I/O sensitive applications), and most 2TB drives are also slow as they are stuck at 7200RPM, and your SATA interface is slow compared to SAS or Nearline-SAS Given that combination of slowness, that array will be slow to perform under for any I/O-sensitive task. The RAID6 array is currently 'initializing' which uses a high amount of I/O and normally only happens when an array is new and them performance is going to be bad until that initialization is complete. Did you put VMs on a brand new array?

Comment: Also, I believe the 3ware 9650SE cards were End-of-Life'd in 2013. Your card is quite old.

Comment: I had the same issue on a 9750-8e when I tried migrating from RAID 5 to RAID 6 (new drives, new array, copied data over).  Less than 1 day after building the RAID 6 it failed for an unexplained reason, all the drives were fine.  I had a bunch of kernel hung messages at the same time the failure occurred.  Went back to RAID 5 and had no problems since.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski None of those are reasons for complete starvation. It may get slower, but the fact that a process doesn't get *any* IO for 120 seconds is abnormal to me. BTW, as I said, the initialising is not the issue, see post. Also, I think the SAS interface isn't the bottleneck, because they outperform the disks. Having said all that, this server is a few years old, and I was planning on using RAID10 in the future, but still this server should not act like this, I feel.

Comment: A broken disk shouldn't lead to a state of 'initializing' it should lead to a state of 'repairing'.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski it took up my spare and it's state went to 'rebuilding'. When that was done, it went to 'initialising'. Now it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be the answer to a related question I asked about [which device to change the scheduling settings on](https://serverfault.com/q/660575/31475). Long story short, this server has its devices configured as multipath for some reason, and that means you don't change the scheduler on `/dev/sdc`, but on `/dev/dm-1` (in my case). The results speak for themselves, machines are no longer bothering each other:

[image]

Indeed, deadline scheduler works much better than CFQ for virtual machines on shared storage.